# Fetch data from table, then change something Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, fetch

[image: I have table named People (as you can see on image)]

I have a `Person` model and `PersonController` for above pictured `People` table.

I want to select all from table and order by rank (rank is who has more points) like this:

```php
    $people = Person::orderBy('rank','desc')->get();
```

My issue lies in the fact that, when I order by rank, I want to add the resulting position (1, 2, 3, ...) as a column in my result.

PS: in the above picture of my table, the person named *Luana* that has most of points should have the position 1, then the person named *sadasda*, at position 2, etc.

Comment: Do you really need this is your result set? I mean, the position is the `index + 1` of the corresponding `Person` model in your `$people` array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the result you are referring to, when you use the get request, all the columns in the table have been taken out.
If you need to add some other fields, you can use the map method of Collection

```php
$people = Person::orderBy('rank','desc')->get();
$people->map(function($item){
   $item->test = 1;
});
```

Comment: I have a Boost button on profile of each person, if you click you add +10 points to rank column, based on rank i want to show each person position (most population, with most points) in this case Luana(if you saw image) has most of points, and shes position should be 1, then it will goes 2,3,4,5,6..